# Where to find the conf for DropWizard embedded http server?

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard, http-status-code-413

We have an application (Restful api) built using DropWizard. When we try to post with a body with size 906KB, it throws exception "413 Request Entity Too Large" error.

I googled around and see the solution seems to change the http server (ngix, apache) config to increase the allowed limit. Where can I find this config for the DropWizard embedded http server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just successfully made a POST request with a 2MB document do a Dropwizard 1.3.14 application. Are you sure that this status code is not caused by some reverse proxy sitting in front of you Dropwizard application?

Comment: @LutzHorn, I am using intellij directly run the code. For this case, do you know where is the proxy setting?

Answer (score 1):

Dropwizard is using [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) under the hood.

You can find a list of exposed configuration settings in the [Dropwizard configuration reference in the "Connectors" category](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.14/docs/manual/configuration.html#connectors).

But as LutzHorn already mentioned in the comments, there's no default limit for the HTTP request size.